# Rest API giving NULL in response

Tags: php, rest, curl, postman, zoho

I am working with `rest API`. I am using [zoho API's](https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/bugs-api.html#alink3) for making calls. Working in `yii2` I am trying to call a `GET` API which gives me some details about my project.

```
   /* Set the Request Url (without Parameters) here */
    $request_url = 'https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/[PORTALID]/projects/[PROJECTID]/bugs/defaultfields/';
    $ch  = curl_init($request_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('authtoken' => 'key')); // here i am using key but in actual i am putting the real key value
    $curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
    $json = json_decode($curl_response);
    var_dump($json);
    exit();
```

Accessing it via `POSTMAN` when I run this call it gives me `NULL` in response. I have also tried out the way mentioned in the PHP Example [here](https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/examples.html). But it doesn't work out for me as well.

I must be missing something that I don't know.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what are you getting in `$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); ` in status??

Comment: it's `int(0)` in status code

Comment: You're aware that `[PORTALID]` and `[PROJECTID]` are placeholders?

Comment: it means you are missing something or host not found kind of error. recheck the url you are passing and check you are not missing any header

Comment: @miken32 I am using actual `PORTALID` and `PROJECTID`. And yes they are correct

Comment: You should make your sample code more clear; use variables where appropriate.

Comment: @miken32 more details are mentioned [here](https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/examples.html)

Comment: I don't need more details; you just need to make things easy to understand. Does your live code have a space before the URL like in your question? What is cURL returning? Does it show any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking your headers and make sure you're passing through all the required fields for an example authorization, content type etc.